# prepareForSegue into view controller with a container view

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, containers, segue

I have a storyboard with two main view controllers (ViewController / SecondViewController) and a container with an embedSegue that displays the EmbeddedViewController view.

**Desired Result**

I would like to pass the 5 from ViewController to EmbeddedViewController using prepareForSegue (I don't see a need for delegation here, since the data is only going 1 way, and that's TO the EmbeddedViewController.) Once "Segue" button is pressed, the second view controller appears with the yellow VC embedded with 5 in it.

*Note - SecondViewController has no user interaction in displaying EmbeddedViewController. It just shows up automatically.*

**Problem**

I can't get a reference to EmbeddedViewController from the mainSegue prepareForSegue. Nor can I access any child View Controllers from SecondViewController. Thought I could access properties of EmbeddedViewController if I access the children VC's of SecondViewController. See code below.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "mainSegue" {
        let secondVCSegue = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondViewController
        print("array -- \(secondVCSegue.childViewControllers)")
        //  Array prints nothing. Just a blank [] :(
    }

}
```

[image: My storyboard layout]

Any tips are appreciated thanks.

Comment: You should get a call to `prepareForSegue` in the second view controlller with the `embedSegue` as the argument. EmbeddedViewController will be the `destinationViewController` for this segue.  You will need to pass the "5" to the second view controller and have it pass it on to the embedded view controller

Comment: So I need to pass the 5 to the SecondViewController, and then another pass to EmbeddedViewController? In theory, that sounds a little strange (and messy) since the only segue on SecondViewController is an embed segue. I'll follow your outline though and give this a shot. Thanks!